# When enter a number in a cell to select a range of cells and print them

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a range print by entering a number in a cell. If a person enter a number 20 (this is just an example, for the real thing it will scan barcode and with a formula will take the number from another table but the basics are like this)... so when the number 20 in in the cell to select the first 20 rows from column B and print this selection. Then to delete all the 20 rows.

I have only the print code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celltxt As String
celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "") Then

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Range("D2") <> "" Then
 Range("D2").PrintOut
 Range("E2").ClearContents
 Application.SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
 End If
 Next ws

Else

End If

End Sub
```

This code is just simple code for printing a cell if the cell in not empty. I am using it but I need to upgrade it with the above idea. :)

If anyone have idea how to create this I will be grateful as I am just a VBA beginner.

[image]

Comment: I believe you want a `Worksheet_Change` event, not a `Selection Change` event. Do you want the macro to fire every time you select a cell or only when they change the value of `D2`?

Comment: The idea is when someone scan a barcode in E2 (check the 2nd picture) to take a number (let say 20 or 40 etc from a table by vlookup). This number will be hidden in E2. By this number to select the corresponding number of cells from B1 (if it's 20 - B1:B20) and print them. Then to delete rows and clear E2.

P.S. The whole scanning cell could be in another sheet, so when deleting the rows not to affect it.

Comment: And yes, you are right, I need the macro to fire only when D2 is changed. But I still need some way to select and print the specific cells. :)

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for this one too with FINALISE

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim celltxt As String
Dim n As Range
'H2 is where the entry number is going to be
 Set n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2")
  On Error GoTo Finalise
 'Select Column C and H2 number
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(n, 3)).Select

celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "") Then
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In Worksheets
 If ws.Range("H2") <> "" Then
 Selection.PrintOut
 Range("H2").ClearContents
 'Application.SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
 End If
 Next ws

Else

End If
Finalise:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Select
End Sub
```

Next... How can I make the code to take the data from another worksheet. Lets say H2 is at sheet1 and the data that should be selected `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(n, 3)).Select` is at Sheet2. At the end of my code I used `ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Select` but still need to get back to H2 in Sheet1.

Also my step after this is to clear all the selected rows content after the print.